# Insert hebrew into mySql datebase threw php

Tags: php, mysql, hebrew

Im trying to insert hebrew letters into my datebase but i get an syntax error when doing that.

```
You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near...
```

My table and the columns are in utf8_general_ci.

I just cant figure out why I keep getting the error over and over again!!!

Here is my connection and code to insert date:

```
//Connect DB via function.php
function connectSQL(){
    mysql_connect(LOCALHOST, DB_USER, DB_PASS) or die("MySQL Error: " . mysql_error());
    mysql_select_db(DB_DATE) or die("MySQL Error: " . mysql_error());
}
connectSQL();
```

Date from page:

```
$sql = mysql_query("INSERT INTO resourses (
                            title, url_title, seo_key, seo_dec, img, time, content, cat) 
                        VALUES(
                            '$title','$url_title','$seo_key','$seo_dec','$img',now(),'$content','$cat'
                        )") or die (mysql_error());
```

Comment: **MySQL is depreciated**. No more using now

Comment: You might have a ' in your variables

Comment: What do you mean by Depreciated?
And i don't have an ' because when I don't add Hebrew letters i don't get the error

Comment: Deprecated means it's no longer supported. As of PHP version 7, mysql is gone. We suggest you switch to PDO or MySQLi. It's a bit different, but much better. And it's easy to get a hang of. Also, what line are you getting this error on and can you give us that line? Also, which version of php are you using, webserver, xampp? Some more info and code could help us a lot!

Comment: Also, try something like this:     $content = utf8_encode($content) 
Then try and add it to the database

Comment: Perhaps you should escape string values with `mysql_real_escape_string()` or similar functions. And use mysqli instead of mysql so your code is compatibe with latest php versions and more secure.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you set the connection charset to utf8:

```
mysql_connect($host, $user, $pass);
mysql_select_db($db);
mysql_set_charset("utf8");
```

And have cleaned your string:

```
$string = mysql_real_escape_string($string);
```